# How to send personalized email in phplist

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer, phplist

Is there a way that I can send personalized emails to different users on the same list in phplist? for example i composed this message:

Dear [name] 
This is the content

If there is a way to modify the [name] to send emails with the actual name of the recipient how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Stack overflow is about programming, not on how to use applications

Comment: This is actually related to the programming, coz the functionality doesn't support by default and I am asking how to do it programmatically

Comment: Doesn't this http://docs.phplist.com/TemplatesInfo solve your problem?

Comment: You can use [phplist templates](http://docs.phplist.com/TemplatesInfo.html) to solve your problem.

Comment: @Mujhaid, and I have now posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you store the user list on a MySQL database, so just simply select the users from the database, and then send a mail to every user on each round of the loop, using result from the query. For example,

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail_list");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $message = "Dear $row['username']";
        $message .= "More...";
        $phpmailer->mail($row['email'], $message, $header); // just for example
    }
?>
```

Figure it out yourself, the code might not fit your context, good luck (:

Comment: +1 for asking to vote up and build the community. 
@Mujahid: You should accept and vote up the answer that helped you solve the problem. That keeps the Stackoverflow's ecosystem going.

Comment: I found another way to solve this issue too. They have an option to create user defined fields. I create a field name as 'Name' and in the template page, I mentioned as [Name], now everything's working fine without any code editing, thanks

Comment: @Mujahid, kindly post your solution in order to help other